# Sitemap xml in node for google console

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, sitemap

Im trying to add a sitemap at Google Search Console.

I have this code:

**Route**

```
router.get("/sitemap", function(req, res){
   res.render("sitemap.ejs");
});
```

**Sitemap.ejs**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sitemap</title>
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="" href="sitemap.xml" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But when i try to add the sitemap to google it says that the sitemap cant be in html format.

How can i make it valid to Google Search Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
var path = require("path");
router.get('/sitemap.xml', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path', 'sitemap.xml'));
});
```